# Optimal 9-element sorting network that reduces to an optimal median-of-9 network?

Tags: algorithm, median, sorting-network

I am looking into sorting and median-selection networks for nine elements based exclusively on two-input minimum / maximum operations. Knuth, *TAOCP Vol. 3*, 2nd ed. states (page 226) that a nine-element sorting network requires at least 25 comparisons, which translates into an equal number of `SWAP()` primitives or 50 min / max operations. Obviously a sorting network can be converted into a median-selection network by eliminating redundant operations. The conventional wisdom seems to be that this does not result in an optimal median-selection network. While this seems to be empirically true, I can find no proof in the literature that this is necessarily so.

Lukáŝ Sekanina, "Evolutionary Design Space Exploration for Median Circuits". In: *EvoWorkshops*, March 2004, pp. 240-249, gives the minimal number of min / max operations required for an optimal nine-input median-selection network as 30 (table 1). I verified that this is achieved both by the well-known median-selection network given by John L. Smith, "Implementing median filters in XC4000E FPGAs". *XCELL magazine*, Vol. 23, 1996, p. 16, and the median-of-9 network from the earlier work of Chaitali Chakrabarti and Li-Yu Wang, "Novel sorting network-based architectures for rank order filters." *IEEE Transactions on Very Large Scale Integration Systems*, Vol. 2, No. 4 (1994), pp. 502-507, where the latter converts into the former by simple elimination of redundant components. See variants 4 and 5 in the code below.

Examining published optimal nine-element sorting networks for suitability for conversion into efficient median-selection networks through elimination of redundant operations, the best version I managed to find is from John M. Gamble's [online generator](http://pages.ripco.net/~jgamble/nw.html), which requires 32 min / max operations, so just two shy of the optimal operation count. This is shown as variant 1 in the code below. Other optimal sorting networks reduce to 36 min / max operations (variant 2) and 38 min / max operations (variant 3), respectively.

Is there any known nine-element sorting network (i.e. with 50 two-input min / max operations) which reduces to an optimal nine-input median-selection network (with 30 two-input min / max operations) through elimination of redundant operations alone?

The code below uses `float` data as a test case, since many processors offer minimum / maximum operations for floating-point data but not integer data, GPUs being one exception. Due to issues with special floating-point operands (which do not occur in my actual use case), optimal code sequences typically require the use of "fast math" modes offered by compilers, such as in this [Godbolt testbed](https://godbolt.org/g/W5Zzrg).

```c++
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>

#define VARIANT     1
#define FULL_SORT   0

typedef float T;

#define MIN(a,b) std::min(a,b)
#define MAX(a,b) std::max(a,b)
#define SWAP(i,j) do { T s = MIN(a##i,a##j); T t = MAX(a##i,a##j); a##i = s; a##j = t; } while (0)
#define MIN3(x,y,z)  MIN(a##x,MIN(a##y,a##z))
#define MAX3(x,y,z)  MAX(a##x,MAX(a##y,a##z))
#define MED3(x,y,z)  MIN(MAX(MIN(a##y,a##z),a##x),MAX(a##y,a##z))
#define SORT3(x,y,z) do { T s = MIN3(x,y,z);  T t = MED3(x,y,z);  T u = MAX3(x,y,z); a##x=s; a##y=t; a##z=u; } while (0)

/* Use sorting/median network to fully or partially sort array of nine values
   and return the median value
*/
T network9 (T *a)
{
    // copy to scalars
    T a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8;
    a0=a[0];a1=a[1];a2=a[2];a3=a[3];a4=a[4];a5=a[5];a6=a[6];a7=a[7];a8=a[8];

#if VARIANT == 1
    // Full sort. http://pages.ripco.net/~jgamble/nw.html
    SWAP (0, 1);   SWAP (3, 4);   SWAP (6, 7);   SWAP (1, 2);   SWAP (4, 5);
    SWAP (7, 8);   SWAP (0, 1);   SWAP (3, 4);   SWAP (6, 7);   SWAP (0, 3);
    SWAP (3, 6);   SWAP (0, 3);   SWAP (1, 4);   SWAP (4, 7);   SWAP (1, 4);
    SWAP (2, 5);   SWAP (5, 8);   SWAP (2, 5);   SWAP (1, 3);   SWAP (5, 7);
    SWAP (2, 6);   SWAP (4, 6);   SWAP (2, 4);   SWAP (2, 3);   SWAP (5, 6);
#elif VARIANT == 2
    // Full sort. Donald E. Knuth, TAOCP Vol. 3, 2nd ed., Fig 51
    SWAP (0, 1);   SWAP (3, 4);   SWAP (6, 7);   SWAP (1, 2);   SWAP (4, 5);
    SWAP (7, 8);   SWAP (0, 1);   SWAP (3, 4);   SWAP (6, 7);   SWAP (2, 5);
    SWAP (0, 3);   SWAP (5, 8);   SWAP (1, 4);   SWAP (2, 5);   SWAP (3, 6);
    SWAP (4, 7);   SWAP (0, 3);   SWAP (5, 7);   SWAP (1, 4);   SWAP (2, 6);
    SWAP (1, 3);   SWAP (2, 4);   SWAP (5, 6);   SWAP (2, 3);   SWAP (4, 5);
#elif VARIANT == 3
    // Full sort. Vinod K Valsalam and Risto Miikkulainen, "Using Symmetry 
    // and Evolutionary Search to Minimize Sorting Networks". Journal of 
    // Machine Learning Research 14 (2013) 303-331
    SWAP (2, 6);   SWAP (0, 5);   SWAP (1, 4);   SWAP (7, 8);   SWAP (0, 7);
    SWAP (1, 2);   SWAP (3, 5);   SWAP (4, 6);   SWAP (5, 8);   SWAP (1, 3);
    SWAP (6, 8);   SWAP (0, 1);   SWAP (4, 5);   SWAP (2, 7);   SWAP (3, 7);
    SWAP (3, 4);   SWAP (5, 6);   SWAP (1, 2);   SWAP (1, 3);   SWAP (6, 7);
    SWAP (4, 5);   SWAP (2, 4);   SWAP (5, 6);   SWAP (2, 3);   SWAP (4, 5);
#elif VARIANT == 4
    // Chaitali Chakrabarti and Li-Yu Wang, "Novel sorting network-based 
    // architectures for rank order filters." IEEE Transactions on Very
    // Large Scale Integration Systems, Vol. 2, No. 4 (1994), pp. 502-507
    // sort columns
    SORT3 (0, 1, 2);
    SORT3 (3, 4, 5);
    SORT3 (6, 7, 8);
    // sort rows
    SORT3 (0, 3, 6);  // degenerate: MAX3 -> a6
    SORT3 (1, 4, 7);  // degenerate: MED3 -> a4
    SORT3 (2, 5, 8);  // degenerate: MIN3 -> a2
    // median computation
    SORT3 (2, 4, 6);  // degenerate: MED3 -> a4 has rank 4
#elif VARIANT == 5
    // John L. Smith, "Implementing median filters in XC4000E FPGAs", 
    // XCELL magazine, Vol. 23, 1996, p. 16
    SORT3 (0, 1, 2);
    SORT3 (3, 4, 5);
    SORT3 (6, 7, 8);
    a3 = MAX3 (0, 3, 6);  // a3 has rank 2,3,4,5,6
    a4 = MED3 (1, 4, 7);  // a4 has rank 3,4,5
    a5 = MIN3 (2, 5, 8);  // a5 has rank 2,3,4,5,6
    a4 = MED3 (3, 4, 5);  // a4 has rank 4
#else 
#error unknown VARIANT
#endif

#if FULL_SORT
    // copy back sorted results
    a[0]=a0;a[1]=a1;a[2]=a2;a[3]=a3;a[4]=a4;a[5]=a5;a[6]=a6;a[7]=a7;a[8]=a8;
#endif

    // return median-of-9
    return a4;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure this will meet all the criteria for what you're looking for, but here's a way to transform variant 5 into a 25-swap, 50-min/max sorting network, and then reduce it to a 30-min/max median-selection network:

We start with the median-selection network (John L. Smith, 1996) which uses three SORT3's, one MAX3, one MIN3 and two MED3's:

[image]

We change all the MAX3, MIN3 and MED3's into SORT3's, and add four SWAP's to get a full sorting network:

[image]

*(We don't need full sorting of triples 1,2,3 and 5,6,7 at the end, because 2 cannot be less than both 1 and 3, and 6 cannot be greater than both 5 and 7.)*

When we replace the SORT3's by SWAP's, we get this standard 25-swap sorting network:

[image]

We can then reduce it to this 30-min/max median-selection network:

[image]

```js
MIN = Math.min; MAX = Math.max;

function sortingNetwork9(a) {        // 50x min/max
    swap(0,1); swap(3,4); swap(6,7);
    swap(1,2); swap(4,5); swap(7,8);
    swap(0,1); swap(3,4); swap(6,7);
    swap(0,3); swap(3,6); swap(0,3);
    swap(1,4); swap(4,7); swap(1,4);
    swap(5,8); swap(2,5); swap(5,8);
    swap(2,4); swap(4,6); swap(2,4);  
    swap(1,3); swap(2,3);
    swap(5,7); swap(5,6);

    function swap(i,j) {var tmp = MIN(a[i],a[j]); a[j] = MAX(a[i],a[j]); a[i] = tmp;}
}
function medianSelection9(a) {       // 30x min/max
    swap(0,1); swap(3,4); swap(6,7);
    swap(1,2); swap(4,5); swap(7,8);
    swap(0,1); swap(3,4); swap(6,7);
     max(0,3);  max(3,6);  // (0,3);
    swap(1,4);  min(4,7);  max(1,4);
     min(5,8);  min(2,5);  // (5,8);
    swap(2,4);  min(4,6);  max(2,4);  
     // (1,3);  // (2,3);
     // (5,7);  // (5,6);

    function swap(i,j) {var tmp = MIN(a[i],a[j]); a[j] = MAX(a[i],a[j]); a[i] = tmp;}
    function min(i,j) {a[i] = MIN(a[i],a[j]);}
    function max(i,j) {a[j] = MAX(a[i],a[j]);}
}
var a = [5,7,1,8,2,3,6,4,0], b = [5,7,1,8,2,3,6,4,0];
sortingNetwork9(a);
medianSelection9(b);
document.write("sorted: " + a + "<br>median: " + b[4]);
```

Comment: How does the proposed sorting network "reduce to an optimal nine-input median-selection network (with 30 two-input min / max operations) *through elimination of redundant operations alone*"? From the Knuth-graph representation, it looks like it would reduce to a median-selection network with *36* two-input min / max operations?

Comment: @njuffa It only does so if you transform it to use the 3-operand swaps, so it may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 3-operand swaps. As the question states, the best solution so far is variant 1, which reduces to 32 min/max operations when going from the sorting to the median network. I am still testing your network in my test scaffolding, and it seems like it may actually reduce to fewer operations than the graph seems to suggest, i.e. it looks *quite promising*. But I need to make sure I am not confusing myself in examining this too quickly. I'll spend some quality time with your proposal before I come back with a final verdict.

Comment: @njuffa It is very similar to Knuth's. If it turns out to be useful, that would be a happy accident, because I think I simply misinterpreted your question.

Comment: If this works as desired (and first indications look good; I am exited now), I will be happy to accept and add a 50-point bonus. Did you create this sorting network in response to my question, or does this reflect prior work of yours, possibly published or in a draft publication?

Comment: @njuffa Your question caught my eye because I'd looked into sorting networks before, but not median selecting networks. I actually simply looked at variants 4 and 5, and tried to add what was necessary to turn it into a full sorting network, and it turned out to be relatively simple to find a solution that resulted in 25 swaps. It was just curiosity, I'm not a CS student or professional.

Comment: It works! Here are the link to Compiler Explorer (godbolt) for illustration. When built as a [sorting network](https://godbolt.org/g/FHpwJp), there are 50 min/max operations; but when compiled to [extract the median](https://godbolt.org/g/PiDnyD), there are 30 min/max operations. I tested the function in my test scaffold to make sure it works correctly.

Comment: @njuffa Now I'll have to edit my answer to make it look like I knew what I was doing :-) (I guess the highly symmetrical nature of the median network I started with, and of the swaps I added to make it a sorting network, are somehow connected to it being an optimal solution.)

Comment: I think the answer is fine as-is. Your idea of starting with an optimal median-selection network and adding the minimal number of swaps to make it into a full sorting network is a great way of tackling the problem that obviously had eluded me; I was too focused on the opposite direction. The graphs explaining your work step-by-step are great, too.