# convert sorting network to median network for small data set

Tags: algorithm, median, sorting-network

I can generate the some good sorting network from here:
http://pages.ripco.net/~jgamble/nw.html

But what I want is to reduce the number of operations in a given sorting network to get median.

My question is, is there any convenient way to achieve this without manually convert it myself? I only need median network for small data set, such as 3, 5, 9, 11, 13, 15.

Comment: whoever voted to close this question, could you plz at least give me a reason?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to just implement the Quickselect algorithm? It's not an optimal median network, but it's very fast: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect. The worst case is O(n^2), but simple modifications can make that case extremely rare. Another option is to do heap selection, which in practice also will be quite fast on such small arrays.

Comment: I'm already aware of quick select and it is slower than sort for small data set. Same as heap selection.

Comment: Just find all the comparators on which the finding of the median value does not depend and delete them. That sounds like something that could be easily achieved with dependency graphs.

Comment: Thanks is there any tutorials that explain this process? Or any terms that I can google by myself?

Comment: @james Not really, just look at what other people do, for example the picture with the red symbols representing the dropped comparators in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46801450/1364752